# Chart.js value manipulation

Tags: javascript, charts

I really need this bad for my project. I'm using Chart.js and so far was able to create a doughnut chart. The main problem that I have is how to manipulate the values of the chart according to how I need them to be displayed. For example, the first value for the gender is 240(male), I would like to add 40 to that number according to what month I would select on my dropdown list(not included on code). Is there a way to manipulate those values?

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Chart JS</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="block">     
<canvas id="gender" width="256" height="256"> <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
var ctx = $("#gender").get(0).getContext("2d");
            //pie chart data
            //sum of values = 360
            var data = [
                {
                    value: 240,
                    color: "cornflowerblue",
                    highlight: "lightskyblue",
                    label: "Male"
                },
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "lightgreen",
                    highlight: "yellowgreen",
                    label: "Female"
                }
            ];
            //draw
            var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
        });
    </script>

 </div>


<div class="block">
<canvas id="agegroup" width="256" height="256">
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var ctx = $("#agegroup").get(0).getContext("2d");
            //pie chart data
            //sum of values = 360

            var n = 10;
            var data = [
                {
                    value: 240,
                    color: "cornflowerblue",
                    highlight: "lightskyblue",
                    label: "Male"
                },
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "lightgreen",
                    highlight: "yellowgreen",
                    label: "Female"
                }, {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "#E54343",
                    highlight: "#CE7373",
                    label: "Female"
                },

                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "lightgreen",
                    highlight: "yellowgreen",
                    label: "Female"
                },

                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: "lightgreen",
                    highlight: "yellowgreen",
                    label: "Female"
                }



            ];
            //draw
            var piechart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
        });
    </script>


</div>

</body>
</html>
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you write the dropdown code with all its values, by month? [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2448618/ryan-arellano)

Comment: I'm still trying to work on it as it is, but the value for Jan is 20 male and 30 female which should make that value 240 to 260 males 150 females.